# Files on jump drive suddenly unavailable-- error "The file “scan-2005-5-19-07.jpg” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: permission, preview

I am using MacOS 10.12.6 on a 2009 Mac with 12 gigs of memory. I have 34 folders of old scans on a jump drive. They are important legal documents so I must solve this problem.

The scans are jpg files, not pdfs. This morning I opened a few of them as normal in Preview. This afternoon - nothing changed - Preview gives me "The file “scan-2005-5-19-07.jpg” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it."

All the files, in every folder, show the same error. What happened? I used sudo chown -R admin to recursively change the permissions on every file and folder. No effect.

Here's what I don't understand: 1) although I can't open the files in Preview, they open just fine in Finder Quick Look (which is ok, except that I can't print them), and Get Info shows the following permissions: admin(Me) Read & Write, staff Read only and everyone Read only. Also, VLC  and GIMP will open the files.

The problem seems to be Preview-specific.

Comment: Jump (thumb, stick, USB) drives, while convenient, are not immune from directory corruption and susceptible to damage from static shock and physical degradation. Copy the files to an internal or external disk and attempt to open them from there.  If they open in Preview then something is wrong with the jump drive. Get a new jump drive and copy the files over to a **new jump drive**.

Comment: _Caveat:_ Don't trust jump drives. I never use them except for ephemeral convenience where the lost data can easily be replaced. I keep all my important archived files in encrypted disk images on three different cloud services, in addition to having rotating Time Machine drives which are physically swapped to another location monthly. If there's an event big enough to destroy both Time Machine backups and my computers, I'll have a lot more to worry about than immediate access to data. If the cloud services are gone, I'll be worrying about survival.